# How to insert Image in database from <img> html that already recieving image from another table

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, file-upload

I have a page that receiving information from database correctly, and I have a button below name as approve, I want that when a click button all details save on database with image, I am using img html tag because I want it to display on page before approving.
Here is the code:

```
    <img name="img" type="file" accept="image/*" src="upload/<?php echo $row['file_name']?>"  style="width: 200px;" height="200px;">
 <button type="submit" name="approve" class="btn btn-default submit-review">Approve Post</button>
```

It recieves an image from database correctly, but I want same image will be upload in relevant column but all the other details are inserting except image:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['approve'])) {

           $location = $_POST['location'];
           $description = $_POST['description'];
           $details = $_POST['details'];
           $type = $_POST['propertytype'];
           $price = $_POST['price'];
           $image = $_FILES['img']['name'];
           $target = "approve/".basename($image);
          $data = "INSERT INTO approve_property (location, description, details, type, price, file_name) VALUES ('$location', '$description', '$details', '$type', '$price', '$image')";
         mysqli_query($db, $data);
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        header('location: post-property.php');
    }else{
        header('location: contact-us.php');
    }
  }


   ?>
```

How can I insert the same image that is into different table in another table using img tag?

Comment: This is open to sql injection; use a prepared statement if you don't want your database to suddenly go *POOF!*. You also need to add an `exit;` after each header.

Answer (score -1):

Use a hidden input field.

```php
<img name="img" type="file" accept="image/*" src="upload/<?php echo $row['file_name']?>"  style="width: 200px;" height="200px;">
<input type="hidden" name="image_filename" value="<?php echo $row['file_name']?>">
<button type="submit" name="approve" class="btn btn-default submit-review">Approve Post</button>
```

then retrieve the value by:

```php
$_POST['image_filename'];
```

Comment: please help me! ADD a perfect answer please